# Automatically update lastModified attribute in mongoDB document on change - Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a `lastModified` attribute in my `games` collection. At the moment I have to manually update the `lastModified` attribute on every change (current timestamp).

Is it possible to update this attribute automatically when other attributes of the document will be changed?

I use Meteor 1.0.

**EDIT:**

Sample document:

```
{ "controllerId" : "ACycCfrQuTtuMwjuJ", "body" : "ABC", "userId" : "5iE4P8HPoRCSHe6k8", "lastModified" : ISODate("2015-01-06T15:48:49.346Z"), "_id" : "CQbL49FP9rZkSF7yh" }
```

When changing attribute `body` it should be like this:

```
{ "controllerId" : "ACycCfrQuTtuMwjuJ", "body" : "XYZ", "userId" : "5iE4P8HPoRCSHe6k8", "lastModified" : ISODate("2015-01-06T19:41:19.888Z"), "_id" : "CQbL49FP9rZkSF7yh" }
```

`lastModified` should automatically be updated when one of the other attributes changes.

Comment: Please include sample documents and the intended output to depict your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-can-i-alter-every-document-before-it-is-added-to-the-database), you can abuse the `deny` mechanism to do this for you:

```js
Games.deny({update: function(userId, doc) {
  doc.lastModified = new Date();
  return false;
}})
```

Alternatively you can use [collection hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks). Your exact use case is the example for [before.update](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks#beforeupdateuserid-doc-fieldnames-modifier-options).